# qtbindings mac install error

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I've try to install qtbindings to my iMac, using this command in terminal:

```
gem install qtbindings
```

And I con't get there result. I think it was install incorrect. Well, this is what I get as a result:

```
    iMac-Andrii-3:~ Zayac$ gem install qtbindings
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing qtbindings:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/Zayac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.2
/Users/Zayac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160613-44635-xuhugd.rb extconf.rb

current directory: /Users/Zayac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.2
make "DESTDIR=" clean
mkdir ext/build
mkdir bin/2.3
mkdir bin/plugins
mkdir bin/plugins/accessible
mkdir bin/plugins/bearer
mkdir bin/plugins/codecs
mkdir bin/plugins/designer
mkdir bin/plugins/graphicssystems
mkdir bin/plugins/iconengines
mkdir bin/plugins/imageformats
mkdir bin/plugins/phonon_backend
mkdir bin/plugins/qmltooling
mkdir bin/plugins/sqldrivers
mkdir lib/2.3
cd ext/build; rm -rf CMakeFiles
cd ext/build; rm -rf generator
cd ext/build; rm -rf smoke
cd ext/build; rm -rf ruby
cd ext/build; rm *
rm: *: No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)

current directory: /Users/Zayac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.2
make "DESTDIR="
mkdir ext/build
mkdir: ext/build: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/2.3
mkdir: bin/2.3: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins
mkdir: bin/plugins: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/accessible
mkdir: bin/plugins/accessible: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/bearer
mkdir: bin/plugins/bearer: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/codecs
mkdir: bin/plugins/codecs: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/designer
mkdir: bin/plugins/designer: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/graphicssystems
mkdir: bin/plugins/graphicssystems: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/iconengines
mkdir: bin/plugins/iconengines: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/imageformats
mkdir: bin/plugins/imageformats: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/phonon_backend
mkdir: bin/plugins/phonon_backend: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/qmltooling
mkdir: bin/plugins/qmltooling: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/sqldrivers
mkdir: bin/plugins/sqldrivers: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir lib/2.3
mkdir: lib/2.3: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
cd ext/build; rm -rf CMakeFiles
cd ext/build; rm -rf generator
cd ext/build; rm -rf smoke
cd ext/build; rm -rf ruby
cd ext/build; rm *
rm: *: No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)
cd ext/build; \
cmake -DCMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED_VERSION=2.6 \
-G "Unix Makefiles" \
-Wno-dev \
-DRUBY_EXECUTABLE=/Users/Zayac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby \
..
/bin/sh: cmake: command not found
make: [build] Error 127 (ignored)
cd ext/build; make
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** [build] Error 2

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Zayac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Zayac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/qtbindings-4.8.6.2/gem_make.out
```

I don't know is you need it for help, but: OS X - latest version, Xcode installed (latest version), ruby installed via rvm (as default and active 2.3.0), rails installed (v.4.2.6).

How can I install qtbindings?

Comment: Looking through documentation the gem is very specific on what versions work with which ruby version have a look at [this](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings#rakefile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was pretty easy. Hope it will help others.

To install qtbindings and Qt4 you have to do.

Open the terminal on your Mac OS X and type:

First step:

```
brew install cmake
```

Second step:

```
brew install qt
```

Third step:

```
gem install qtbindings
```

It must solve all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that cmake is missing - I installed it via brew install cmake.

Comment: i've install cmake with your advice, but still the same error

Comment: Run xcode-select install to install the newest Xcode command line tools, install cmake, then try it again wih gem install qtbindings. I also had to recompile my ruby with -enable-shared